# How to perform late loading of page content

Tags: asp.net, loading

I am building a small web application, in my app I am loading certain types of data. Each type takes a different ammount of time. Now, I wouldn't like my whole page to load for years, instead I want my page to load immediatly, show my logo and basic css and then load each content tab separatly. What is the correct way to approach it?

I am working with asp.net and c#.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you are not concerned about accessibility/SEO you can use UpdatePanel and load content using AJAX. You can trigger AJAX update on-page-load.

Comment: what do you mean by accessibility? As to update panel, if I have a custom control that I wish to load that has lots of javascript in it, will it still work?

Comment: your website should work fine even if JavaScript is turned off, so make sure you supply alternative solution for browsers where javascript is not supported.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a fan of them, but iframes could be used for each individual grid of data. They would load as they were called by the main page then and render when they are ready. This would work without javascript.

Comment: yes but I iframes rander differently in different browsers, they're pretty problematic..

Comment: very true, but its a possible solution, it depends on what is needed ultimately. personally i hate iframes and would use ajax.